# The problem with connecting custom fonts to the mediawiki

Tags: fonts, mediawiki

I have a problem adding fonts to mediawiki-1.34.0.

I connect additional css files in **LocalSettings.php** like this:

```
$wgResourceModules['custom.styles.whatever'] = array(
    'scripts' => array(
        '/skins/Vector/resources/js/test.js'
    ),
    'styles' => array(                                             
        '/skins/Vector/resources/css/header-footer.css'
    )
);
function addMyCustomScripts(&$out)
{
    $out->addModules('custom.styles.whatever');
    return true;
}
$wgHooks['BeforePageDisplay'][] = 'addMyCustomScripts';
```

And inside these styles I connect fonts like this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: OpenSansRegular;
  src: url('../fonts/OpenSansRegular.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

And everything works fine on the localhost. But on the server, the CMS is looking for fonts in a strange way: http://skins/Vector/resources/fonts/OpenSansRegular.ttf

The styles are here: root-wiki-dir\skins\Vector\resources\css\

Fonts are here: root-wiki-dir\skins\Vector\resources\fonts\

I don’t understand what needs to be fixed so that the fonts are connected both on the localhost and on the site?

Answer (score 0):

I found a reason. It was just necessary to remove / at the beginning of each path to each resource.

```
 'skins/Vector/resources/css/header-footer.css'
```

My XAMPP Windows server turned // into /, and the Linux server took this as an absolute path, as I understand it.